# Live axle + steering

Tags: technic, vehicle, steering

Does anyone know how to make a live front axle (steered, driven, beam axle, preferably with a panhard rod) in a relatively small space, I can't figure it out.

This is my rear axle for guidance:

[image: 1]

Most things are OK to change except for: suspension mounting points (one stud inwards IS possible), track width, and wheel size.

I appreciate any help, doesn't need to be a finished product, just an idea would go a long way too.

Answer (score 3):

I could suggest looking at suspension in RM8's [Land Cruiser (FJ40) model](http://brickgarage.blogspot.com/2014/12/40-fj40.html). Although all description is in Russian that webpage contains sufficient number of pictures, which are self-explanatory. This model has even got free [instructions](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-2769/RM8%20LEGO%20Garage%20-%20BrickGarage/toyota-land-cruiser-fj40-hard-top-base/#details).

From what I see, both yours and RM8 model's suspension are 11L wide so it could be adapted or pose as an inspiration to figure out your own, unique setup.

[image]

[image]